# How is the coefficient of determination in ANCOVA computed?

Tags: ancova, r-squared

Given the following ANCOVA model:

$Y_{ij}=\mu+\alpha_i+\beta X_{ij}+\epsilon_{ij}$,

$e_{ij}\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ i.i.d.,

$\alpha_1=0$,

$i=1,..., m$,

$j=1,..., n$

Given I have already computed

$SC_{W}=\sum_i\sum_j(y_{ij}-\bar{y}_{i.})(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})$

and

$SS_W(X)=\sum_i\sum_j(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})^2$

how can the coefficient of determination $R^2$ in this model be computed and what is the formula for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of determination $R^2$ is computed by first computing the total sums of squares $SS_T$ and the explained sums of squares $SS_\hat{Y}$:

$SS_\hat{Y} = \sum_i(\hat{y_i}-\bar{y})^2$

$SS_T = \sum_i\sum_j(y_{ij}-\bar{y})^2$

and then dividing $SS_\hat{Y}$ by $SS_T$:

$R^2=\dfrac{SS_\hat{Y}}{SS_T}$